# OpenStack HAproxy issues

Tags: django, openshift, haproxy, django-1.7

I am using [openshift-django17](https://github.com/jfmatth/openshift-django17) to bootstrap my application on Openshift. Before I moved to Django 1.7, I was using authors previous repository for [openshift-django16](https://github.com/jfmatth/openshift-django16) and I did not have the problem which I will describe next. After running successfully for approximately 6h I get the following error:

> Service Temporarily Unavailable The server is temporarily unable to
>   service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems.
>   Please try again later.

After I restart the application it works without any problem for some hours, then I get this error again. Now gears should never enter idle mode, as I am posting some data every 5 minutes through RESTful POST API from outside of the app. I have run rhc tail command and I think the error lies in **HAproxy**:

> ==> app-root/logs/haproxy.log <== [WARNING] 081/155915 (497777) : config : log format ignored for proxy 'express' since it has no log
>   address. [WARNING] 081/155915 (497777) : Server express/local-gear is
>   DOWN, reason: Layer 4 connection problem, info: "Connection refused",
>   check duration: 0ms. 0 active and 0 backup servers left. 0 sessions
>   active, 0 requeued, 0 remaining in queue. [ALERT] 081/155915 (497777)
>   : proxy 'express' has no server available! [WARNING] 081/155948
>   (497777) : Server express/local-gear is UP, reason: Layer7 check
>   passed, code: 200, info: "HTTP status check returned code 200", ch eck
>   duration: 11ms. 1 active and 0 backup servers online. 0 sessions
>   requeued, 0 total in queue. [WARNING] 081/170359 (127633) : config :
>   log format ignored for proxy 'stats' si nce it has no log address.
>   [WARNING] 081/170359 (127633) : config : log format ignored for proxy
>   'express' since it has no log address. [WARNING] 081/170359 (497777) :
>   Stopping proxy stats in 0 ms. [WARNING] 081/170359 (497777) : Stopping
>   proxy express in 0 ms. [WARNING] 081/170359 (497777) : Proxy stats
>   stopped (FE: 1 conns, BE: 0 conns). [WARNING] 081/170359 (497777) :
>   Proxy express stopped (FE: 206 conns, BE: 312 co

I also run some CRON job once a day, but I am 99% sure it does not have to do anything with this. It looks like a problem on Openshift side, right? I have posted [this issue on the github](https://github.com/jfmatth/openshift-django17/issues/16) of the authors repository, where he suggested I try stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out this was due to a bug in [openshift-django17](https://github.com/jfmatth/openshift-django17) setting DEBUG in settings.py to True even though it was specified in environment variables as False (pull request for fix [here](https://github.com/jfmatth/openshift-django17/pull/18)). The reason 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable appeared was because of Openshift [memory limit violations](https://help.openshift.com/hc/en-us/articles/202399600-How-to-check-for-memory-limit-violations) due to DEBUG being turned ON as stated in [Django settings documentation for DEBUG](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#debug):

> It is also important to remember that when running with DEBUG turned on, Django will remember every SQL query it executes. This is useful when you’re debugging, but it’ll rapidly consume memory on a production server.